# Equilibrium concentrations of CO and Cl2 by dissociation of phosgene

Tags: organic-chemistry, equilibrium, kinetics, decomposition

I am working through a problem set from MIT's open courseware course [Principles of Chemical Science](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/5-111sc-principles-of-chemical-science-fall-2014/517e9ef9c38ea95d3c03876dc53a44c9_MIT5_111F14_Lec18Prob.pdf).

The question is:

> Phosgene $\ce{(COCl2)}$ is a chemical warfare agent that decomposes by the reaction:
> $$\ce{COCl2(g) <=> CO(g) + Cl2(g)}$$
> $K= 8.3 \times 10^{-4}$ (at $\pu{360 ^\circ C}$)
>
> Calculate the $\ce{[CO], [Cl2],}$ and $\ce{[COCl2]}$ when $\pu{10.0 mol}$ of phosgene decomposes at $\pu{360 ^\circ C}$ and reach equilibrium in a 5.00-L flask.

I am a bit unsure whether equilibrium constant given is the ratio of partial pressures, or concentration of gases. ($K$ or $K_\mathrm{c}$)

### My first approach is assuming that $K$ is given (not $K_\mathrm{c}$):

Given: $T =\pu{360 ^\circ C} = \pu{633.15 K}$

1. Convert $K$ to $K_\mathrm{c}$

   $K = (RT)^{\Delta n_\mathrm{r}} \cdot K_\mathrm{c}$

   $K_\mathrm{c} = \dfrac{K}{(RT)^{\Delta n_\mathrm{r}}}$

   $K_\mathrm{c} = \dfrac{8.3 \times10^{-4}} {(8.3145 \times10^{-2} \cdot 633.15)^1}$

   $K_\mathrm{c} = 1.577 \times10^{-5}$
2. Calculate starting concentration of $\ce{COCl2}$

   $[\ce{COCl2}] = \dfrac{\pu{10.0 mol}}{\pu{5.00 L}} = \pu{2.00 mol L-1} $
3. Calculate equilibrium concentration of each species: 
   $\begin{align} 
   & [\ce{COCl2}] = 2.00 - x \\
   & [\ce{CO}] = x \\
   & [\ce{Cl2}] = x \\
   & K_\mathrm{c} = \dfrac{[\ce{CO}][\ce{Cl2}]}{[\ce{COCl2}]} = \dfrac{x^2}{2.00 - x}
   \end{align}$

   Using ($K_\mathrm{c} = 1.577 \times10^{-5}$ above): (ignoring negative solution for $x$)

   $x = 5.608 \times10^{-3}$

   $\begin{align} 
   & [\ce{COCl2}] = 2.00 - 5.608 \times10^{-3} = \pu{1.99 M} \\
   & [\ce{CO}] = \pu{5.61 \times10^{-3} M }\\
   & [\ce{Cl2}] = \pu{5.61 \times10^{-3} M} \\
   \end{align}$

### The solutions given [here](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/5-111sc-principles-of-chemical-science-fall-2014/4d0d7db1079f4fee2bdd58d95033f36d_MIT5_111F14_Lec18Soln.pdf) are:

> $$\begin{align} 
> & [\ce{COCl2}] = \pu{1.96 M }\\
> & [\ce{CO}] = \pu{0.041 M} \\
> & [\ce{Cl2}] = \pu{0.041 M} \\
> \end{align}$$

I'm not quite understanding why my answer is different.

### My second approach is to determine the partial pressures of each species at equilibrium:

1. Calculate initial partial pressure using 
   $\begin{align}
   & P_\mathrm{\ce{COCl2}} = \dfrac{n_\mathrm{\ce{COCl2}}RT}{V} \\
   & P_\mathrm{\ce{COCl2}} = \dfrac{10.0}{5.00}RT \\
   & P_\mathrm{\ce{COCl2}} = \pu{105.2 bar}
   \end{align}$
2. Calculate equilibrium pressures of each species: 
   $\begin{align} 
   & P_\mathrm{\ce{COCl2}} = 105.2 - x \\
   & P_\mathrm{\ce{CO}} = x \\
   & P_\mathrm{\ce{Cl2}} = x \\
   & K = \dfrac{P_\mathrm{\ce{CO}}P_\mathrm{\ce{Cl2}}}{P_\mathrm{\ce{COCl2}}} = \dfrac{x^2}{105.2 - x}
   \end{align}$

   Using ($K = 8.3 \times10^{-4}$ above): (ignoring negative solution for $x$)

   $x = 0.294 $

   $\begin{align} 
   & [\ce{COCl2}] = \dfrac{P_\mathrm{\ce{COCl2}}}{RT} = \dfrac{105.2 - 0.294}{RT} = \pu{1.99 M}  \\
   & [\ce{CO}] = \dfrac{0.294}{RT} = \pu{5.59 \times10^{-3} M} \\
   & [\ce{Cl2}] = \dfrac{0.294}{RT} = \pu{5.59 \times10^{-3} M} \\
   \end{align}$

### My last approach is to assume that the problem set has given me $K_\mathrm{c}$

I get much closer to the given answer.

1. Calculate equilibrium concentration of each species: 
   $\begin{align} 
   & [\ce{COCl2}] = 2.00 - x \\
   & [\ce{CO}] = x \\
   & [\ce{Cl2}] = x \\
   & K = \dfrac{[\ce{CO}][\ce{Cl2}]}{[\ce{COCl2}]} = \dfrac{x^2}{2.00 - x}
   \end{align}$

   **Using ($K = 8.3 \times10^{-4}$)**: (ignoring negative solution for $x$)

   $x = 0.0403$

   $\begin{align} 
   & [\ce{COCl2}] = 2.00 - 0.0403  = \pu{1.96 M} \\
   & [\ce{CO}] = \pu{0.040 M }\\
   & [\ce{Cl2}] = \pu{0.040 M }\\
   \end{align}$

I'm still off by one significant figure.

Thanks for your help. Sorry in advance for any inconsistent formatting.

Comment: First off, you're only off by 0.0002 because that's what it would take to round up. Second, sig figs are a terrible way to do this in general, even though we teach this all the time... Also, I suspect they took the first root (-0.041) and didn't look clearly at the negative sign.

Comment: Your last approach is the correct one. Given answer might have approximation problem (see Zhe's comment).